# Perl $self in different subs

Tags: perl

I've got the following structure in my Perl App

```
sub new {                                   
    my $self = {};
    $self->{'orcl'} = undef;
    $self->{'cgi'} = CGI->new();
    bless $self;
    return $self;
}

sub getJ {
    my $self = shift;
    my $requestmethod = $self->{'cgi'}->request_method;
    $self->{'orcl'} = dbconnect();
    if($requestmethod eq 'POST') {
        my $testvar = anotherSub();
    }

sub anotherSub {
    my $self = shift;
    my $sth = $self->{'orcl'}->functionToFetchRow();
}
```

In the sub "dbconnect" the connection to the Database is opened.
So my problem is now, that I get the Error "Can't call method "functionToFetchRow()""

If I do

```
$self->{'orcl'} = dbconnect();
```

In the sub "anotherSub" it works perfect. But I want to open the connection to the Database only once and not in every Sub where I need it.

So wheres my fault here?

Comment: You are missing a curly bracket at the end of the sub `getJ`. Show us some real code on which you actually saw your problem. Also, I doubt you gave us the complete error message (it probably ends with *on an undefined value*).

Comment: You should start indenting your code properly. It's hard to read. You also seem to have mixed OOP code and normal functions in the same package. If `sub dbconnect` is defined in that package it should be a method and also be called with `$self`. If it's imported, you shouldn't import it, but use the fully qualified name including the package because otherwise it will be available as a method on your object later. You should also include a `$class` (which is like `$self`, but holds the package name) in `sub new` and then `bless` into that class or you will be unable to subclass later.

Comment: Consider posting your actual full code (or a working subset that you feel comfortable sharing publicly on the internet) on [codereview.se] in the Perl tag and we'll give you feedback about your style and tell you how you can improve your code.

Comment: Ok thanks. But this is my full code. In the sub dbconnect I only do $self->{'orcl'} = AnotherPackage::Orcl->new(schema, user, db, ....) But you helped me a lot. I think I now understand a bit more how to write Perl OOP. It is a bit hard for me because I programmed the last time in 2010 with php and not OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't call method "functionToFetchRow" on an undefined value

This error message tells you that `$self` is `undef`.

You need to pass `$self` to `anotherSub` or it doesn't know about it. To do that, use the method syntax.

```
if($requestmethod eq 'POST') {
    my $testvar = $self->anotherSub();
}
```

Perl will automatically pass along `$self` as the first argument to `anotherSub` if it's called like that. This is how oject orientation works in Perl.

You are already using the exact same thing when you do `$self->{'cgi'}->request_method` and `$self->{'orcl'}->functionToFetchRow()`. In both cases, the keys inside of `$self` (which is really just a hash reference) contain objects, and the `->method` calls the method on those objects, passing the objects themselves along as the first argument.

Comment: simbabque you are my hero the last days! It works and with your help I understand Perl even more! Thanks!